# Python - Can I update my file using Insert mode?

Tags: python, io

Basically I want to insert text with overwriting other text, like when you click "Insert" button on your keyboard. Is that possible? I really don't want to read all of the lines, I just want to change one letter.

File before:

```
abcd
```

Code:

```
with open(file, INSERT) as f:
    f.seek(1)
    f.write('e')
```

File after:

```
aecd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do exactly what you are saying, this should do the trick:

```
with open(file, 'r+') as f:
    f.seek(1)
    f.write('e')
```

Output:

```
aecd
```

Comment: This is however not recommended, especially if using an encoding with variable byte size. This could remove too much or not enough.

Comment: Agree but it is what it was asking

Comment: The comment was general, for potential future readers (you can add it to the answer if you like) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found an [answer to a similar question from way back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1593658/10504841). Here is an updated version of the answer I found (tailored for your needs):

```py
import os,mmap

with open("test", "r+b") as f:
     mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
     mm[1:2] = b"e"
     mm.close()
```

Output

`aecd`

[mmap documentaion has a similar example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html)